# axios на клиенте не получает данные с удаленного сервера

Tags: javascript, веб-сервер, express, клиент-сервер, axios

Вел разработку приложения клиент-сервер с локальным сервером. Когда сервер запущен локально, все работает. 
А с удаленным сервером какие-то проблемы возникают.

Клиент успешно отправляет запрос, сервер его успешно получает, успешно обрабатывает и отправляет ответ, а на клиенте на этапе приема -- ошибка
(На клиенте используется Axios, на сервере express)

На всякий случай прикрепляю пример запроса на клиенте и обработчика на сервере, но с ними должно быть все в порядке, т.к., повторюсь, с локальным сервером все работает

**пример запроса с клиента:**

```
axios.get(url, { params: params })
      .then(response => {
        setLoading(false);
        if (!response) return null;
        return response.data;
      }).catch(err => { 
        setLoading(false);
        setError(err.message);
        console.log("В ответе от сервера ошибка!!!: ", err);
        return null;
      })
```

**Пример обработчика на сервере:**

```
router.get("/cars", async (req, res) => {
  connection.query(
      "SELECT make.name as mark, model.name as model, body.name as body \n" +
      "from make \n" +
      "INNER JOIN model on make.id_mrk=model.id_mrk \n" +
      "INNER JOIN body on model.id_mdl=body.id_mdl",
      (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error of mysql query: " + "Запрос на получение списка моделей, марок и кузовов");
          return;
        }

        const result = {};

        response.forEach(row => {
          if (!result[row.mark]) result[row.mark] = {};
          if (!result[row.mark][row.model]) result[row.mark][row.model] = [];


          result[row.mark][row.model].push(row.body);
        });


        console.log(`Отправляю данные о машинах`);
        res.status(200).json(result);
      }
  );
});
```

на сервере никаких ошибок, запрос к БД проходит успешно;

ошибка на клиенте выглядит так:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я был слегка невнимателен и не заметил уведомление об ошибке CORS. Проблема была вызвана тем, что клиент запускался локально и отправлял их скрипта запросы на удаленный сервер, для решения достаточно было реализовать получения клиентской части посредством запроса на сервер (тогда и запросы из этой клиентской части на этот же сервер не блокируются)